# Possible jQuery Tools Tooltip bug using latest jQuery 1.7.1 - d is undefined

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

Trying to do a simple example of a jQueryTOOLS Tooltip (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html) keeps giving:

IE7,8,9 reports:
Unable to get value of the property 'jquery': object is null or undefined 
jquery.tools.min.js, line 25 character 1057

FireFox reports it as: "d is undefined"

I'm using the latest jQuery and jQuery UI:

1. jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2. jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
3. jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css
4. (I then have to do the jQuery.noConflict(); because of previous
   years of work using $)
5. then I'm including jQuery Tools v1.2.6

I then try the absolute basic test just like they have on their page:http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

and I keep getting that error. I have tried IE7,8,9,Chrome,FF,Safari all with same result. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I used this instead. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Worked first time.  Just had to change

```
                $("#eleId a[title]").tooltip();
```

to

```
                $("#eleID a").tooltip();
```

and add the CSS.